# Proving non-degenerate extreme points in a cube in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Is there a simple, concise way to show that any cube in $\Bbb R^3$ will *always* have a no-degenerate extreme point? The one in my text expands on nearly five pages, which confuses me much.

This can be found in the textbook

> Introduction to Linear Programming by L.N. Varserstein

Comment: can you share the text, where the proof is mentioned, may be I can help in deducing a shorter proof

Comment: @LalitPathak, edited for your reference